# Is there a way to type check addition with maybe types in flow-typed safely?

Tags: types, flowtype

The following will throw a `null/undefined. The operand of an arithmetic operation must be a number.` error as expected:

```
/* @flow */
function foo(x: ?number): number {
  return 1 - x;
}
```

[try here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoKBXAdgYwC4CWcWYUccAFAB4BcYA-FhgLYBGApgE4CUdTbXMAG9UYMJ3Z4MnEgEYwAWjBUA3KgC+qIA)

Yet changing `-` to `+` will make it check:

```
/* @flow */
function foo(x: ?number): number {
  return 1 + x;
}
```

and everything is "fine" [try here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoKBXAdgYwC4CWcWYUccAFAB4BcYA-FhgLYBGApgE4CUdTbXMAG9UYMJ3Z4MnEgEYwAajBUA3KgC+qIA)

except it will cause an `NaN` for `null` or `undefined` as input.

Is there a way to type check addition with maybe types in flow-typed safely? Or is this a bug like [this](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3887)? (in which case I will happily file a bug report)

(edit: flow-typed@2.1.5)

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: There is a bug ticket at the flow-typed repo: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2452